# Unable to publish messages to GCP Pub/Sub using Python SDK when executed via Cron inside a GKE POD

Tags: python-2.7, cron, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-kubernetes-engine

Using a PYthon SDK to publish messages to GCP Pub/SUb. THe code is running inside a Kubernetes POD on GKE.

```
import pymysql
import os
import argparse
import time
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

entries = ['jelly']

def publish_messages(project, topic_name):

  publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
  topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project, topic_name)

  for n in entries:
    data = u'Message number {}'.format(n)
    data = data.encode('utf-8')
    publisher.publish(topic_path, data=data)
    print "Message %s sent to queue" % n
```

Script works fine when executed manually. However, it fails when triggered via Crontab.

```
Error: No handlers could be found for logger google.cloud.pubsub_v1.publisher._batch.thread"
```

Comment: Also check the topic name and project name. If its incorrect then also it it gives this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution. 
Crontab by default doesn't read from the system environment variables. And this Python code above needs the env variable "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" which holds the service Account key (ConfigMap in this case). 
To achieve this all the env variables must be printed out to "/etc/environment" file of the container on the runtime.
Something like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ADD send.py Jelly/send.py
COPY jellycron /etc/cron.d/jellycron
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron vim mysql-server curl python python-pip 
    && pip install --upgrade pymysql google-api-python-client google-cloud google- 
    cloud-pubsub && touch /var/log/cron.log && chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/jellycron && 
    crontab /etc/cron.d/jellycron
CMD printenv >> /etc/environment && cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```